# Understanding of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: electromagnetism, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics

For some background, I transferred into physics from bio without taking hs precalc/ physics.
In my E&M lecture notes (not homework), my professor introduced the equations:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} P_l (x) P_{l'}(x) dx = \frac{2}{2l+1} \delta_{ll'}. $$

$$ \sum_{l = 0}^{\infty} \frac{2l+1}{2} P_l(x)P_l(x') = \delta(x-x'). $$

Why must the Legendre polynomials be orthogonal to project out coefficients and expand by integrating? How is this similar to FTs? Is there a good intro resource you can recommend to learn the relevant info for E&M?

Comment: Since your query is about mathematics it would probably benefit you more to ask the [math.se] stackexchange. Have you tried looking up what the Legendre Polynomials are on Wikipedia/mathworld?

Comment: Note: This kind of maths is often taught on the go in physics courses. In my studies, such things did not occur in the math courses (perhaps as an example in a functional analysis course I took much later than the theoretical EM course).

Comment: @SebastianRiese really? I encountered them really early in my ODE/PDE courses before I saw them in physics. I suppose it might be situational based on institute. Perhaps OP might want to invest in a mathematics for physicists textbook to cover many of the things to show up, there is a decent one by Wiley they could use.

Comment: @Triatticus Probably highly dependent on institution and country (although, I believe the curriculum to have been quite representative for Germany). I only had a dedicated ODE/PDE course as because I did additional mathematical courses.

Comment: (I had a first semester course on mathematical methods for physicists, that teaches things like solving ODEs, basics of PDEs, vector calculus, etc. with physicist's notation and (lack of) rigour – albeit very compressed and cursory. The maths proper in the first two semesters was an analysis course together with the mathematics students – this covered everything from the absolute fundamentals like constructions of number spaces, metric spaces, point-set topology, convergence, etc. up to multivariate calculus, but no differential equations or integral theorems beyond Gauß).

Answer (score 1):

Legendre-polynomials indeed have similarities with Fourier transform. Both are a complete orthogonal systems, i.e. they form a basis of a Hilbert space. For Legendre-polynomials it is  $L^2[-1,1]$, all functions between in the interval between -1 and 1 which is square-integrable can be developed in an (infinite) linear combination of the basis, the Legendre-polynomials $P_n(x)$. If you have basis in the Hilbert-space  --- here it is $P_n(x)$ --  one can expand a function $f\in L^2[-1,1]$ like:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n P_n(x)$$

Like in a finite vector space one can express the coefficients as scalar product of the vector to be expanded and the basis elements. The vector to be expanded is in this case $f(x)$:

$$  a_n =\frac{2n+1}{2}< f(x), P_n> = \frac{2n+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(x) P_n(x) dx $$

The scalar product in this space is given by the Lebesgue integral:

$$<a(x), b(x) > =  \int_{-1}^1 a(x) b(x) dx $$

So in the end we have:

$$ f(x) = \sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty \frac{2l+1}{2} < f(x), P_l> P_l(x)$$

which corresponds to the finite vector space relation:

$$ v = \sum\limits_{l=0}^n <v,e_l> e_l$$

This explains that coefficients can be "projected out".
The relationship

$$\sum\limits_{l=0}^\infty \frac{2l+1}{2} P_l(x) P_{l'}(x') = \delta(x-x')$$

is called completeness property and assures that the basis of Legendre-polynomials is really complete, i.e. each $L^2[-1,1]$-function can be expressed in Legendre-polynomials.

Periodical functions also are members of a Hilbert-space, but it is another one. But the general rules are the same:  There is exists a complete basis, in this case the trigonometric functions. And the coefficients can be computed by the given scalar product of the chosen periodical function and the basis elements. This is the foundation of Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is similar to Fourier transforms.  The orthogonality is similar to the orthogonality of the eigenvectors for Hemitian matrices. Are you familiar with the theory of eigenvectors?  An introductory  book on quantum mechanics usually discusses this.  Also  as standard math methds books for physics, such as Riley, Hobson and Bence "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering: A Comprehensive Guide" will have a good coverage.

Answer (score 0):

My answer tries add some intuition by appealing to how things work in finite dimensional vector spaces (and hints to why you have to be careful with the analogies).

#### Developing a vector in a basis

The polynomials $P_l$ form a basis of the functions on $[-1, 1]$ (more specifically the $L^2$-functions) – just like the unit vectors $(\vec e_i)_{i=1\ldots n}$ span the finite dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is similar to how a finite dimensional vector $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written in a basis${}^*$:
$$ \vec x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec e_x \tag{1} $$

In the same vein we can write for $f \in L^2([-1,1])$:
$$ f = \sum_{l=0}^\infty f_l P_l(x).  \tag{1'} $$

#### The completeness relation

That all functions can be represented in this way is specified in your second equations (usually called the completeness relation):
$$ f(x) = \int dx' f(x') \delta(x - x') = \int dx' f(x') \sum_l \frac{2l+1}{2} P_l(x) P_l(x') = \sum_l P_l(x) \underbrace{\frac{2l+1}{2} \int dx' f(x') P_l(x')}_{=:\,f_l}. $$
(Note the plethora of things that are potentially dangerous here form a rigour standpoint – changing the order of the integral with an infinite sum, the careless manipulations of the $\delta$-distribution.)

The corresponding finite dimensional formula to the completeness relation is
$$ \mathbf{1} = \sum_i \vec e_i \circ \vec e_i. $$
(That is, the base vectors span all the vector space!)

#### The orthogonality relation

The orthogonality relation, allows to uniquely project out a coefficient from the representation $(1')$:
$$\frac{2l+1}{2} \int dx P_k(x) \sum_l f_l P_l(x) = \frac{2l+1}{2} \sum_l f_l \int dx P_k(x) P_l(x) = \sum_l f_l \delta_{lk} = f_k $$

In finite dimensions the orthogonality relation looks like (what is presented here is slightly stronger, it's an ortho*normality* condition):
$$ \vec e_i \cdot \vec e_j = \delta_{ij} $$
And the orthogonality allows us to project out the coefficients of components easily:
$$ \vec e_j \cdot \sum_i x_i \vec e_i = \sum_i x_i \vec e_j \cdot \vec e_i = \sum_i x_i \delta_{ji} = x_j $$

#### Analogy to Fourier analysis

The analogy to Fourier analysis is, that the funciton $e^{ixp}$ also form a basis of a function space (namely $L^2(\mathbb{R})$).

#### Disclaimer

${}^*$ In physics we typically don't really care, but we run into trouble when extending the concept of a basis from finite dimensional (like $\mathbb{R}^n$ to infinite dimensional vector spaces (like $L^2([-1,1])$).

While in the finite dimensional case $(1)$ holds as an algebraic identity, in infinite dimensional spaces you would need *uncountably* many basis vectors to represent all vectors.

To overcome this, we need help from topology (which gives us a concept of convergence). Often, we add a norm based on an inner product to a vector space. On $L^2(X)$ this is the $L^2$-inner product, and norm:
$$ \left< f, g \right> = \int_X dx f(x) g(x), $$
$$ \left\| f \right\| = \sqrt{\left<f, f\right>}. $$

A series of functions $(f_i)$ now converges to a function $f$, if
$$ \lim_{i \to \infty} \left\| f_i - f \right\| = 0. $$

With this we can define countable infinite sums as the limit of the partial sums:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^N f_i. $$

In finite dimensional spaces all this does not matter, as all norms are equivalent, and the algebraic identity $(1)$ holds with finitely many basis vectors.

There are many further subtleties – sometimes more general notions of convergence are used ("weak convergence"), $\delta$ is not an element of the function space (but rather of the space of distributions, which are the continuous linear functions on some space of test functions, ... *insert functional analysis curriculum here*).